# Sync newsletter custom checkbox between checkout and my account in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, account

I would like to synhcronize a custom checkbox field in WooCommerce checkout page with a similar one in the My Account page (when the user is logged in).

Here's my code:

```
// Show a checkbox in checkout page and in My account > Details

add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'display_checkbox_in_account_page' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'display_checkbox_in_account_page' );

function display_checkbox_in_account_page() {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'newsletter-account', array(
        'type'  => 'checkbox',
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __( 'Subscribe to my newsletter', 'woocommerce' ),
    ), get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'newsletter-account', true ) );
}


// Save checkbox value when saved in My account > Details

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_checkbox_value_from_account_details', 10, 1 );
function save_checkbox_value_from_account_details( $user_id ) {
    $value = isset( $_POST['newsletter-account'] ) ? '1' : '0';
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'newsletter-account', $value );
}
```

Those two blocks of code work fine: if in My account > Details I checked the checkbox, the preference is saved and I can see a checked checkbox also in the checkout page.

Now the problem is that I need a way to obtain the same result when I edit my newsletter preference from the checkout page. I think I need to use the woocommerce_checkout_create_order but I haven't any idea on how to code this:

```
//Save the checkbox value when customer edit it from the checkout page

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_checkbox_value_from_checkout_page'. 10, 1 );

function save_checkbox_value_from_checkout_page() {
    //some code here
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

The hook `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` is for **order meta data** and what you need is to save/update your checkout `newsletter-account` field value as **user meta data**…

> So is better to use dedicated `woocommerce_checkout_update_customer` hook.

Here is your complete code (tested and working):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'display_checkbox_in_account_page' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'display_checkbox_in_account_page' );
function display_checkbox_in_account_page() {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'newsletter-account', array(
        'type'  => 'checkbox',
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __( 'Subscribe to my newsletter', 'woocommerce' ),
    ), get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'newsletter-account', true ) );
}


// Save/update checkbox value when saved in My account > Details
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_checkbox_value_from_account_details', 10, 1 );
function save_checkbox_value_from_account_details( $user_id ) {
    $value = isset( $_POST['newsletter-account'] ) ? '1' : '0';
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'newsletter-account', $value );
}

// Save/update custom checkout field value as user meta data
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_customer','custom_checkout_checkbox_update_customer', 100, 2 );
function custom_checkout_checkbox_update_customer( $customer, $data ){
    $value = isset( $_POST['newsletter-account'] ) ? '1' : '0';
    update_user_meta( $customer->get_id(), 'newsletter-account', $value ); // Updated
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

---

Now if you want to grab that information additionally to the order as **order meta data** you will use:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order','custom_checkout_checkbox_add_order_meta', 100, 2 );
function custom_checkout_checkbox_add_order_meta( $order, $data ){
    $value = isset( $_POST['newsletter-account'] ) ? '1' : '0';
    $order->update_meta_data( 'newsletter-account', $value );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your precious help! This solves my problem!

Comment: @Davide You should [delete this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57755250/3730754) as it's a duplicate (also the answer is not accepted and doesn't work).